# How to alter the histogram bin widths?

Tags: r

my code is as follows:

```
hist(df2, main = paste("Histogram of Mutual Fund Survival Times"), xlab = "Number of Months", ylab = "Frequency of Mutual Funds", labels = TRUE, ylim=c(0,350))
```

My bin widths are currently 50. I would ideally like to change the first bin to a width of 36 and leave the rest at 50. Is this possible?

If not, all bin widths at 36 are fine.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create bins with the `breaks` argument of `hist`. The breaks are the lower limit of each bin. They can be whatever you want. Here is an exaggerated example. In generates some errors, but it works.

```
hist(runif(n = 1000, min = 1, max = 100), breaks = c(1, 2, 10, 25, 100))
```

[image]

Rather than manually provide the breaks, you can have R calculate them from your data:

```
hist(x, breaks = c(min(x), seq(min(x) + 36, max(x), 50)))
```